# Programmatically create ShapeDrawable

Tags: android, drawable

I'm trying to programmatically create a ShapeDrawable but the following code doesn't show anything.

```
ImageView image = new ImageView (context);
image.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams (200, 200));
ShapeDrawable badge = new ShapeDrawable (new OvalShape());
badge.setBounds (0, 0, 200, 200);
badge.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
ImageView image = new ImageView (context);
image.setImageDrawable (badge);
addView (image);
```

I can get it working with xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:width="200px"
        android:height="200px" />
    <solid
        android:color="#F00" />
</shape>

ImageView image = new ImageView (context);
image.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams (200, 200));
image.setImageResource (R.drawable.badge);
addView (image);
```

But I would like to create it programmatically. The xml works perfectly so the problem can't be with the ImageView, it must be in creating the ShapeDrawable.

Comment: Did you try setting layout bounds to your imageview? PLease add the information about the layout where you add the imageview to

Comment: What is the point of this? ImageView image = new ImageView (context); for the second time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `setIntrinsicWidth` and `setIntrinsicHeight` instead of `setBounds` to set the width and height.

```
ImageView image = new ImageView (context);
image.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams (200, 200));
ShapeDrawable badge = new ShapeDrawable (new OvalShape());
badge.setIntrinsicWidth (200);
badge.setIntrinsicHeight (200);
badge.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
image.setImageDrawable (badge);
addView (image);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create a Class extending ShapeDrawable to override `onDraw` and then create an instance of your class.

**Example:** ([Source](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-4/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ShapeDrawable1.java.shtml) - check link for full example)

```
private static class MyShapeDrawable extends ShapeDrawable {
            private Paint mStrokePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

            public MyShapeDrawable(Shape s) {
                super(s);
                mStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            }

            public Paint getStrokePaint() {
                return mStrokePaint;
            }

            @Override protected void onDraw(Shape s, Canvas c, Paint p) {
                s.draw(c, p);
                s.draw(c, mStrokePaint);
            }
        }
```