# android: create custom shape with state programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable

How can I create shape with state in Kotlin(or java)
for example I want create below shape with Kotlin(or java)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="999dp" />
        <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="#bfbfbf" />
        <solid android:color="#f44336" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="999dp" />
        <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#E0E0E0" />
        <solid android:color="#f44336" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="999dp" />
        <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#E0E0E0" />
        <solid android:color="#f44336" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="999dp" />
        <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="#bfbfbf" />
        <solid android:color="#f44336" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I see this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578701) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642224) but i wonder how to create state to drawable

Comment: see `StateListDrawable`

Comment: thanks @pskink , That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: sure, your welcome